# How can i change the color of text being input by the user

Tags: python

Beginner here, was trying to make the board game 'mastermind' in python to test what I'd learned. Here the user has to input any 4 colors and they are compared with 4 pre-selected colors...

I want to know if its possible to change the text color of the user entered colors (for example the user enters 'red' so i want 'red' to be printed in red color.)

I have tried colorama but apparently that only works with text in the code as i don't know where the user is going to input what..
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

(If you'd like to see my code I can share it but i don't think its going to be any help :) )

Answer (score 4):

Depending upon what the user has entered as the input, you can add the following code in "print" to display the contents in a particular color

```
 print("\033[1;32;40m your text  \n")
```

Here '\033' is the escape sequence, which will remain same everytime

1 is for normal style.

32 is the color code for green

And 40m is for the background (black)

For more reference take a look at this-

http://ozzmaker.com/add-colour-to-text-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ***colorama***

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style

print(Fore.BLUE + "Hello World")
```

[image]

Here you can find more details.

https://pypi.org/project/colorama/